# Hybrid rendering (Server + Client Side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

I want to create an e-commerce platform that requires pages rendered on the server (initial state computed on the server) but with react or vue components for filtering that change the initial state by fetching the filtered data using api calls.

Do you know any javascript framework that support combining server and client side rendering in one route/page ?

Comment: you can use `Next.js`

Comment: Recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I don't ask for recommendations, I ask about tools that make this possible. I don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Next JS can make this happen. It supports both server and client side rendering.

Here is an example that combines both :

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function EventList({ eventList }) {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(eventList)
  const router = useRouter()

  const fetchSportsEvents = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/events?category=sports')
    const data = await response.json()
    setEvents(data)
    router.push('/events?category=sports', undefined, { shallow: true })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={fetchSportsEvents}>Sports Events</button>
      <h1>List of events</h1>
      {events.map(event => {
        return (
          <div key={event.id}>
            <h2>
              {event.id} {event.title} {event.date} | {event.category}
            </h2>
            <p>{event.description}</p>
            <hr />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default EventList

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { query } = context
  const { category } = query
  const queryString = category ? 'category=sports' : ''
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/events?${queryString}`)
  const data = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      eventList: data
    }
  }
}
```